# Invalid .htaccess file Command

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just got this site sent to me because a page is not loading, instead it is showing a 500 error. I migrated the entire site over to my localhost and looked at my log. It shows that it is an Invalid Command on RewriteCompatability2. I'm currently looking into this, but would love some extra eyes on this.  Especially since I've never had this problem come up, or really dealed with mod_rewrites too much. Here is the code:

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.78

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCompatibility2 On

RepeatLimit 200

RewriteBase

#RewriteRule ^products/[^?/]*_(\d+)\.asp /productpage.asp?productID=$1 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^/categories/(.*)$ /category.php?c=$1  [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/categories/(.*) /category.php?c=$1
#RewriteRule ^/contact(.*) /contact.php
#RewriteRule ^/order(.*) /order.php
#RewriteRule ^/about(.*) /about.php
#RewriteRule ^/privacy(.*) /privacy.php
#RewriteRule ^/search/(.+) /search.php?search=$1

RewriteRule  ^/$ /index.php [PT]
RewriteRule ^/categories/(.*) /category.php?c=$1    [PT]
RewriteRule ^/contact(.*) /contact.php  [PT]
RewriteRule ^/order(.*) /order.php  [PT]
RewriteRule ^/about(.*) /about.php  [PT]
RewriteRule ^/privacy(.*) /privacy.php  [PT]
RewriteRule ^/search/(.+) /search.php?search=$1 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCompatibility2` is a [ISAPI_Rewrite 3 directive](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteCompatibility2.htm). You should not use it with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Okay, but as soon as I took it out RepeatLimit is taking its place. That should be gone too I suppose?

Comment: Cool, but now my log is showing RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context